# MySQL sum with a special condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

So i would like to sum the points from one of my table.
My table structure looks like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | piece | points |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |     3 |   1200 |
|  2 |     1 |    700 |
|  3 |     2 |    950 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

I would like to sum the points, but where the piece is more than 1 i would like to multiplicate the points with the piece number.
I have this code:

```
SELECT SUM(points) AS points_sum FROM table
```

But this is only sums the points once.
I what i want is understable.
I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: what would be your expected result from the above sample data ?

Comment: The final data would be 3*1200+700+2*950 = 6200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(piece*points) as points_sum
FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
POINTS_SUM
6200
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/367151/2).

Comment: I was just about to praise and upvote this answer as it is quick, correct and have `SQL fiddle` as well. Whats the problem in this answer? And same answer below is upvoted. What is going on here...?

Comment: Downvoter MUST MUST mention the reason of downvote in comment...I think, this should be included in SO architecture.

Comment: But i dont think that this is the correct solution as per the problem asked by @user3575457

Comment: As per the @user3575457 pproblem if points are more than 1 then only he wants to multiply not every time. When piece is 1 the points must be same as in the column. In that case your query will not work properly.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: To be honest, there is no difference in both ways. And I think my answer is more readable too. Since the answer is accepted, I am sure that OP is looking for this query and I did work for him.

Comment: But as per my undrestandability, the answer is not appropriate. I have attached the SQL Fiddle as well. So u can check the difference there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT SUM(points*piece) AS points_sum FROM table
```

Comment: As per the @user3575457's pproblem if points are more than 1 then only he wants to multiply not every time. When piece is 1 the points must be same as in the column. In that case your query will not work properly.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: And what is the difference between returning the number and returning the same number multipied by 1?

Comment: Still you didn't use Group By Clause

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Why should Niemand use a GROUP BY clause. OP didn't ask for that.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Why should I GROUP BY to anything if OP want only 1 column with a sum as a result. I don't get your downvoting for me and RagingBull, everything works as he asked to work.